# Is there PHP code I can use to automatically detect which link should use a CSS active property?

Tags: php, html, css

Sorry if that wording was confusing - I am very new to PHP, as I am designing a website for my small organization and only have previous experience in CSS and HTML.

Basically, I included the header and footer in the site using a PHP include so that it would only take one update to change all the links, as it is a pretty big site with a lot of pages that would take forever to update in HTML.

The problem I am having now is that since the php include is only one page, no matter what page you are on, the category in the header menu that is 'active' and highlighted blue is the one that I originally copied the menu from to create the .php file. Obviously, I want it to be whatever menu category you are actually in, and not just that same one every time. I am sure there is a very easy way to do this in PHP, but I was having trouble finding anything because I wasn't exactly sure how to word the question when I searched for it. Thanks in advance to anybody who can help!

Comment: you  need to it manually using if conditions and using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method, using a global variable and a lot of conditional logic:

Any file on your site:

```
<?php
$current_page = 'name of page here';
include('menu.php');
... page content/logic here ...
```

menu.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($current_page)) { $current_page = 'home'; }
?>

<ul id="menu">
   <li<?php ($current_page == 'home') : ' class="current"' : '' ?>>Home</li>
   <li<?php ($current_page == 'foo') : ' class="current"' : '' ?>>foo</li>
   etc...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your menu look like, but you can test the current page with PHP_SELF

```
<?php
$urls = array('index.php', 'include7.php', 'about.php');
$current_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // if for example you are in /folder/index.php ; the basename will output only 'index.php'
?>
<?php foreach ($urls as $url): ?>
    <a href="<?=$url;?>" style="color: <?= ($url==$current_page) ? 'green' : 'red'?>"><?=$url;?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In my example, I was in include7.php file, so in the output, only it was colored green, other 2 were colored red.

Answer (score 0):

The method I prefer of doing this uses no PHP logic at all. In each of your pages, add a class to a high-level element, such as `body`:

```
<body class="home">
```

Then in the menu, add a matching class name to each menu option:

```
...
<li class="home"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li class="whatever"><a href="/whatever">Whatever</a></li>
...
```

And then in the CSS:

```
body.home li.home a,
body.whatever li.whatever a
{
    color: blue;
}
```

...or whatever style you want, using whatever selectors you prefer, the key being that the CSS looks for a matching body and menu item classname, and therefore only highlights the item for the current page.

This means that there's no PHP logic whatever. When you create a new page, add a body class for it, and a matching entry in the menu, and add it to the CSS.

I tend to use this method in situations like yours, when PHP isn't being used as a server-side language or a CMS system so much as a very simple template-builder. It keeps the server-side code very minimal, which matches the rest of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it:

1) detect the page you're in from within PHP
2) update the parts of your header/footer that depend on the page you're in

#### detecting the page you're in

The `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` superglobal variable will give you the path of the current page relative to the site root.

For instance, if your page is `http://whatever.site.com/about.php`, it will give you `/about.php`.

It means you can use the name of the current page as a key to change whatever behaviour from within your generic header/footer.
Depending on the way your pages are stored, you can easily synthetize a simple identifier for the current page (something like "index", "about", "contact", etc).

You can then put that in a global `$PAGE` variable allowing you to identify your current page from about anywhere in your PHP code.

#### updating the variable parts

If you need some item to change according to the page you're in (typically highlight the current page in your header), you can easily do it by checking `$PAGE` :

```
<li class='.<?php echo $PAGE=='about'   ? 'selected' : 'unselected' ?>about
<li class='.<?php echo $PAGE=='contact' ? 'selected' : 'unselected' ?>contact
```

You might also want to do some less redundant code generation, for instance:

```
<?php
function menu_items ()
{
    global $PAGE;

    foreach (array ("home", "about", "contact") as $page)
        echo "<li class='.(($PAGE==$page) ? 'selected' : 'unselected')."'>$page";
}
?>

<!-- header menu -->
<ul><?php menu_items(); ?></ul>
```